Azure Synapse Sparkr Notebook: How to load a .yaml file holding credentials from ADLS Gen2 directory
Is it possible to load a .yaml file into a Azure Synapse Sparkr Notebook? How do I load a .yaml file holding credentials from ADLS Gen2 directory?

If your ADLS gen 2 account is your primary ADLS account to your synapse workspace then you will have access to the account without mounting it. Otherwise, mount the account and read .yaml file which is having credentials into a dataframe in synapse notebook using below code:
import yaml
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


# Read the YAML file as text
yaml_file_path = "abfss://<containerName>@<adlsName>.dfs.core.windows.net/inp/cred.yml"
yaml_rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(yaml_file_path)

# Parse the YAML content
yaml_content = yaml_rdd.collect()
yaml_docs = list(yaml.safe_load_all("\n".join(yaml_content)))

# Convert each document into a DataFrame and union them
yaml_dfs = [spark.createDataFrame([doc]) for doc in yaml_docs]
yaml_df = yaml_dfs[0]
for df in yaml_dfs[1:]:
    yaml_df = yaml_df.union(df)

# Display the DataFrame
yaml_df.show()

It will give the below dataframe as output:

